# row to column csv python for multiple values under one heading

Tags: python, export-to-csv

I have the following text file.
dummy.txt

```
Property,Value
status,ACTIVE
updated,2014-04-26T17:01:27Z
OS-EXT_STS:task-state,None
OS-EXT-ATTR:host,noe-001
key_name,dummy-host
image,1234d46g-354f-89fg-23fg-45fhty56fjd7
mine-internalnetwork,192.168.50.10,10.10.80.40
hostId,123g3124h4h32h3h432h4324h2jh423j4h32k4h32jh432j4hj2k342
Property,Value
status,ACTIVE
updated,2014-04-25T17:01:27Z
OS-EXT_STS:task-state,None
OS-EXT-ATTR:host,noe-002
key_name,dummy-host1
image,1234d46g-fh56-8h5g-23fg-4556fhtmggjg
mine-internalnetwork,192.168.49.10,10.10.80.39
hostId,436bx8fbby747ycb4y7535afggoirif947307ffh8tycfu34yxycf84
```

Now, I want to print result like below where value is getting changed for column 2 after property and value.

```
status,updated,OS-EXT_STS:task-state,OS-EXT-ATTR:host,key_name,image,mine-internalnetwork,hostId
ACTIVE,2014-04-26T17:01:27Z,None,noe-001,dummy-host,1234d46g-354f-89fg-23fg-45fhty56fjd7,192.168.50.10,10.10.80.40
ACTIVE,2014-04-25T17:01:27Z,None,noe-002,dummy-host1,1234d46g-fh56-8h5g-23fg-4556fhtmggjg,192.168.49.10,10.10.80.39
```

This is my code:
import csv
import subprocess
import sys
import os

from collections import defaultdict

columns = defaultdict(list)

with open('dummy.txt.txt') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for row in reader:
                for (k,v) in row.items():
                        columns[k].append(v)

print(columns['Property'])
print(columns['Value'])

And the output i am getting as below.

./testdb_update3.py
['status', 'updated', 'OS-EXT_STS:task-state', 'OS-EXT-ATTR:host', 'key_name', 'image', 'mine-internalnetwork', 'hostId']
['ACTIVE', '2014-04-26T17:01:27Z', 'None', 'noe-001', 'dummy-host', '1234d46g-354f-89fg-23fg-45fhty56fjd7', '192.168.50.10', '123g3124h4h32h3h432h4324h2jh423j4h32k4h32jh432j4hj2k342']

dummy.txt file: (this file doesn't contain multiple values, which i tried later and post a question)

status,ACTIVE
updated,2014-04-26T17:01:27Z
OS-EXT_STS:task-state,None
OS-EXT-ATTR:host,noe-001
key_name,dummy-host
image,1234d46g-354f-89fg-23fg-45fhty56fjd7
mine-internalnetwork,192.168.50.10,10.10.80.40
hostId,123g3124h4h32h3h432h4324h2jh423j4h32k4h32jh432j4hj2k342

Comment: What is the question?  Please post an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you are having with your solution.

Comment: Please show your work.

Answer (score 3):

For data you should use Pandas. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import numpy as np

f = open('dummy.txt','r')
text = f.read()

t = np.array([i.split(',')[1] for i in text.split('\n')])
t = t.reshape(len(t)/9,9)

A = df(t[:,1:], columns=['status', 'updated', 'OS-EXT_STS:task-state', 'OS-EXT-ATTR:host', 'key_name',
                'image', 'mine-internalnetwork', 'hostId', ])

for p in A.columns.values:
    print(p,end=', ')
for i in A.values:
    for j in i:
        print(j,end=', ')
    print('\n',end='')
```

Also if you want to import you information to csv (common task), use this command:

```
A.to_csv('out.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: I tried but throwing syntax error:
./testdb_update4.py
  File "./testdb_update4.py", line 27
    print(p,end=', ')
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you print it?
Do you use Python 2 or 3?

Comment: change `print(p,end=', ')` to `print p, ', '` and `print('\n',end='')` to `print '\n'`

Comment: I am using python 2.7.6 and after changing print the error is change" ImportError: No module named pandas". I tried to install pnadas module but looks like it has highly recommended  dependencies "build-essentials and bottleneck". that's not getting installed.

Comment: can we use re module and convert file data as desired to csv

Comment: The most powerful part of python are it's modules, so it's really important to learn how to work with them. What os do you use and you tried to install pandas?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu trusty.